# page load open panel in html using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am using html code with java script and css . i am doing open panel at button click.panel is open but i want to open panel at page load. how to use of call at page load in html.becouse function is call at page load but call is not call at page load how to convert of class in functions.how to solve of this problem

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Simple Slide Panel</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".btn-slide").click(function() {
                    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
                    $(this).toggleClass("active");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
                width: 570px;
                font: 75%/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            a:focus {
                outline: none;
            }
            #panel {
                background: #754c24;
                height: 200px;
                display: none;
            }
            .slide {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border-top: solid 4px #422410;
                background: url(images/btn-slide.gif) no-repeat center top;
            }
            .btn-slide {
                background: url(images/white-arrow.gif) no-repeat right -50px -50px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 144px;
                height: 31px;
                padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
                margin: 0 auto;
                display: block;
                font: bold 120%/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .active {
                background-position: right 12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="panel">
            <!-- you can put content here -->
        </div>
        <p class="slide"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">Slide Panel</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
          $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
            return false;
        });  

        $(".btn-slide").trigger('click');
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
        return false;
    });  

    $(".btn-slide").trigger('click');
});
```